# JavaScript Quiz Not Giving a score from the function

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript Quiz i have been working on and its very close to being finished. I have a check answer function in my JS and it was working, but it has since stopped working and now is not giving me a score when I finish my game. Additionally, it decreases my score by ten for every answer I submit. Even if it is the correct answer.

```js
var quizButton = document.querySelector("#quiz-button")
var timer = 75
var quizTimer = document.querySelector("#quiz-timer")
var questionIndex = 0
var score = 0
var questionBoxElement = document.querySelector('#question-box')



// check for correct answer

function correctAnswer(answerBtn) {
  return answerBtn.textContent === question.answer;
}

// check if answer is correct
function checkAnswer(event) {
  let answerBtn = event.target;
  // correct answer 
  if (correctAnswer(answerBtn)) {
    score = score + 20;
  }
  // wrong answer 
  else {
    if (timer > 10) {
      timer = timer - 10;
    } else {
      timer = 0;
      endQuiz();
    }
  }

  questionIndex++;

  // if no more questions, end quiz
  if (questionIndex < questions.length) {
    displayQuestion();
  } else {
    endQuiz();
  }
}


function endQuiz() {
  let finalScore = document.querySelector("#scores")
  finalScore.textContent = "You scored " + score + "! Great Job!";
}


var questions = [
  // add questions here!!
  // question 1
  {
    questionText: "This is question 1",
    options: ["a. answer", "b. correct", "c. answer", "d. answer"],
    answer: "b. correct"
  },
  // question 2 
  {
    questionText: "this is question 2",
    options: ["a. correct", "b. answer", "c. answer", "d. answer"],
    answer: "a. correct"
  },
  // question 3
  {
    questionText: "This is question 3",
    options: ["a. answer", "b. answer", "c. answer", "d. correct"],
    answer: "d. correct"
  },
  // question 4 
  {
    questionText: "this is question 4",
    options: ["a. answer", "b. answer", "c. correct", "d. answer"],
    answer: "c. correct"
  },
  // question 5
  {
    questionText: "this is question 5",
    options: ["a. answer", "b. answer", "c. correct", "d. answer"],
    answer: "c. correct"
  }
];

var answerBtn0 = document.querySelector("#option0");
var answerBtn1 = document.querySelector("#option1");
var answerBtn2 = document.querySelector("#option2");
var answerBtn3 = document.querySelector("#option3");

var answers = [answerBtn0, answerBtn1, answerBtn2, answerBtn3]

// display questions
function displayQuestion() {
  let question = questions[questionIndex];
  let answerOptions = question.options;

  let questionEl = document.querySelector("#question");
  questionEl.textContent = question.questionText;



  for (var i = 0; i < answerOptions.length; i++) {
    let answerChoices = answerOptions[i];

    let answerBtn = answers[i];

    answerBtn.textContent = answerChoices;

  }



}




// timer countdown
function countdown() {
  var timeLeft = setInterval(() => {

    if (timer >= 0 || questionIndex < 5) {
      quizTimer.textContent = timer + " seconds left";
      timer--;
      //questionIndex ++;

    } else {
      clearInterval(timeLeft);

      // call game over function
    }
  }, 1000);
}


//Start function
function startQuiz() {
  var startQuizIntro = document.querySelector(".start-quiz-intro")
  startQuizIntro.setAttribute("class", "hide")

  questionBoxElement.classList.remove("hide")

  console.log(questionBoxElement);
  // reset timer and score
  userScore = 0;

  countdown();
  displayQuestion();
}


quizButton.addEventListener("click", startQuiz);

document.querySelector("#answer-buttons").addEventListener("click", checkAnswer);
```

```html
<div id="quiz-timer"></div>

<header class="start-quiz-intro">
  <div class="quiz">
    <h2>Coding Quiz</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="center-button">
    <p class="start"> Press Button To Start The Quiz</p>
    <button id="quiz-button">Start</button>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="hero">
  <div id="question-box" class="hide">
    <h2 id="question"></h2>
    <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid">
      <button id="option0" class="btn"></button>
      <button id="option1" class="btn"></button>
      <button id="option2" class="btn"></button>
      <button id="option3" class="btn"></button>
    </div>
    <h3 id="scores"></h3>
  </div>
</div>

<footer>
  Thanks for playing my game - Reid
</footer>
```

Comment: Look, I just made you a working snippet. At least copy the snippet to the new question

Comment: idk how to do that, if i did I would. plus it doesn't work otherwise I wouldn't have re asked the question. Thank you for your help, but is asked you a follow up question on the previous and you didn't respond

Comment: Sorry, I have a life. I just answered. When you make a snippet using the `[<>]` snippet editor, you can edit afterwards and look at the code the snippet created

Comment: Feel free to delete this one

Comment: sorry i hurt your feelings man. im new here so idk what the protocols are. thank you for the help

Comment: No feelings hurt - I broke your script so I had to fix it

Answer (score 1):

You have only to change this line:  `return answerBtn.textContent == question.answer;` in the `correctAnswer` function to `return answerBtn.textContent == questions[questionIndex]['answer'];`

```
function correctAnswer(answerBtn) {
  // return answerBtn.textContent == question.answer; 
  return answerBtn.textContent == questions[questionIndex]['answer'];
}
```

```js
var quizButton = document.querySelector("#quiz-button")
var timer = 75
var quizTimer = document.querySelector("#quiz-timer")
var questionIndex = 0
var score = 0
var questionBoxElement = document.querySelector('#question-box')



// check for correct answer

function correctAnswer(answerBtn) {  
  return answerBtn.textContent == questions[questionIndex]['answer'];
}

// check if answer is correct
function checkAnswer(event) {
  let answerBtn = event.target;
  // correct answer 
  correctAnswer(answerBtn)
  if (correctAnswer(answerBtn)) {
    
    score = score + 20;
  }
  // wrong answer 
  else {
    if (timer > 10) {
      timer = timer - 10;
    } else {
      timer = 0;
      endQuiz();
    }
  }

  questionIndex++;

  // if no more questions, end quiz
  if (questionIndex < questions.length) {
    displayQuestion();
  } else {
    endQuiz();
  }
}


function endQuiz() {
  let finalScore = document.querySelector("#scores")
  finalScore.textContent = "You scored " + score + "! Great Job!";
}


var questions = [
  // add questions here!!
  // question 1
  {
    questionText: "This is question 1",
    options: ["a. answer", "b. correct", "c. answer", "d. answer"],
    answer: "b. correct"
  },
  // question 2 
  {
    questionText: "this is question 2",
    options: ["a. correct", "b. answer", "c. answer", "d. answer"],
    answer: "a. correct"
  },
  // question 3
  {
    questionText: "This is question 3",
    options: ["a. answer", "b. answer", "c. answer", "d. correct"],
    answer: "d. correct"
  },
  // question 4 
  {
    questionText: "this is question 4",
    options: ["a. answer", "b. answer", "c. correct", "d. answer"],
    answer: "c. correct"
  },
  // question 5
  {
    questionText: "this is question 5",
    options: ["a. answer", "b. answer", "c. correct", "d. answer"],
    answer: "c. correct"
  }
];

var answerBtn0 = document.querySelector("#option0");
var answerBtn1 = document.querySelector("#option1");
var answerBtn2 = document.querySelector("#option2");
var answerBtn3 = document.querySelector("#option3");

var answers = [answerBtn0, answerBtn1, answerBtn2, answerBtn3]

// display questions
function displayQuestion() {
  let question = questions[questionIndex];
  let answerOptions = question.options;

  let questionEl = document.querySelector("#question");
  questionEl.textContent = question.questionText;



  for (var i = 0; i < answerOptions.length; i++) {
    let answerChoices = answerOptions[i];

    let answerBtn = answers[i];

    answerBtn.textContent = answerChoices;

  }



}




// timer countdown
function countdown() {
  var timeLeft = setInterval(() => {

    if (timer >= 0 || questionIndex < 5) {
      quizTimer.textContent = timer + " seconds left";
      timer--;
      //questionIndex ++;

    } else {
      clearInterval(timeLeft);

      // call game over function
    }
  }, 1000);
}


//Start function
function startQuiz() {
  var startQuizIntro = document.querySelector(".start-quiz-intro")
  startQuizIntro.setAttribute("class", "hide")

  questionBoxElement.classList.remove("hide")

  console.log(questionBoxElement);
  // reset timer and score
  userScore = 0;

  countdown();
  displayQuestion();
}


quizButton.addEventListener("click", startQuiz);

document.querySelector("#answer-buttons").addEventListener("click", checkAnswer);
```

```html
<div id="quiz-timer"></div>

<header class="start-quiz-intro">
  <div class="quiz">
    <h2>Coding Quiz</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="center-button">
    <p class="start"> Press Button To Start The Quiz</p>
    <button id="quiz-button">Start</button>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="hero">
  <div id="question-box" class="hide">
    <h2 id="question"></h2>
    <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid">
      <button id="option0" class="btn"></button>
      <button id="option1" class="btn"></button>
      <button id="option2" class="btn"></button>
      <button id="option3" class="btn"></button>
    </div>
    <h3 id="scores"></h3>
  </div>
</div>

<footer>
  Thanks for playing my game - Reid
</footer>
```

Comment: It's already answered in the dupe. Please allow OP to delete this

Comment: @mplungjan ok. what means `dupe` ?

Comment: thank you for the help! that change to the correctAnswer function was what I was missing

Comment: Dupe is a Duplicate - reload the page and see the link to the question with a working answer